# Which sentence meaning is most similar to "I march the troops."?

Tags: sentence-meaning

The main sentence is **"I march the troops."**

The others are below.

> 1. I make the troops walk.
> 2. I make the troops walked. (Walked is used as passive form.)

In both sentences, which has same meaning like main sentence ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"I march the troops" is a somewhat odd use of the verb "march", but the sentence means "I make the troops march", which is closest to #1.

> I make the troops walked. (Walked is used as passive form.)

This sentence is not grammatically correct. "Walked" should not be used here, even if the walking occurred in the past. Also, "walked" is not the passive form of "walk".

"Make" is used here as a *causative verb* - the troops are walking *because of you*. To use "make" correctly in this sense, the structure is:

> I (make/made/will make) + (person or thing) + (**base form** of verb)

For example:

> I made her dog fetch the ball.
>
> I make my class follow my instructions.
>
> I will make the children go home.